# Symfony - doctrine createQueryBuilder multiple Joins

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i have this query in MySQL and i want to apply into doctrine

```
SELECT * FROM ads_list AS al LEFT JOIN (ads_category AS ac, ads_category_main AS acm) ON (ac.id = al.category_id AND ac.parent_cat_id = acm.id)
```

do you have any idea how to use this with doctrine ?
i'm using this in a Repository 
parameter goes to `ads_category_main`
so i'm trying to select the `ads_list` with `category` and each category has a parentCategory which is stored in `ads_category_main`

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `ads_list` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`posted_at` date NOT NULL,
`post_xpr` date NOT NULL,
`agency_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`slug` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `ads_category` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`parent_cat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `ads_category_main` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

so far i got

```
    public function findAllP($main)
    {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('pl')
        ->leftJoin('pl.category', 'al')
        ->where('al.parentCat = :pc')
        ->setParameter('pc', $main)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
    }
```

and how do i use the output data in a controller ?

Comment: They have an example in the documentation:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#building-expressions

Comment: Try `getResult()` instead of `execute()`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the entities related you could do the join like

```
->join/leftJoin('entity.foreign_key','alias')
```

if the enitities are not related you must specify the "ON" option of the join.

after that you have some ways to handle the result.

```
$qb->getQuery()->getResult();
$qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```